# How to export in GAP

Tags: export, gap-system

I'm fairly new to programming in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) which is designed for computational algebra.  I have made a computation and wish to make a scatter plot with my results however GAP does not have this functionality.  Is it possible/how/where could I find out if it is possible to export a vector from GAP.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this at GAP Forum or GAP Support as [described here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info), or at least at Math.SE site if you prefer to stay within Stackexchange framework. If CSV format is suitable for your purposes, please see `PrintCSV` [here](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap10.html#X8779DAC585E05A47).

Answer (score 2):

It is not specified in the question which tool is intended to be used to create plots. However, it does not really matter. The most general approach is to create input file(s) for such a tool from GAP, using [`PrintTo` and `AppendTo` commands](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap9.html#X86956C577FFEE1F9). There may be some additional support for some specific formats, for example for CSV in [`PrintCSV`](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap10.html#X8779DAC585E05A47) though.